# When i fetch data from Database,it is fetched.but when i was again and again,it is showing error

Tags: android, json

When i fetch data from Database,it is fetched.but when i was again and again,it is showing error.

The exception thrown is:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond 10-05 17:52:19.653: 
E/Fail 4(626): java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream. 10-05 17:52:19.653: 
E/Fail 3(626): org.json.JSONException: No value for discountOfferPrice 10-05 17:52:20.739: 
E/Fail 3(626): org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond 10-05 17:52:20.739: 
E/Fail 4(626): java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
```

how can i solved this type of problem in android.

Comment: Which database? Which error? Your question is way too broad.

Comment: I am using Mysql database. error like this  org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
10-05 17:52:19.653: E/Fail 4(626): java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
10-05 17:52:19.653: E/Fail 3(626): org.json.JSONException: No value for discountOfferPrice
10-05 17:52:20.739: E/Fail 3(626): org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
10-05 17:52:20.739: E/Fail 4(626): java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.

Comment: Edit the question please.

Answer (score 0):

Your server probably shuts down the connection on its end but yout HttpClient is not able to react to that event.
When the connection is closed NoHttpResponseException is thrown.

You can try and override setHttpRequestRetryHandler:

```
yourHttpClient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {
@Override
public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, int executionCount, 
                            HttpContext context) {
    if (executionCount > yourMaxRetries) {
       //Do something
         return false;
    }
    if (exception instanceof org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) {
        //This is your exception
          return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

});

Comment: can u give the example?how did i use your above code in example?

Comment: This is an example, you should implement it in your code (on your HttpClient instance)